# What would the derivative of this objective function be?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, image-processing

My question comes from image processing community,

In our Machine Learning algorithm, we have a predicted value $D$ and its equivalent ground truth $D^*$

where their difference is: $d_i=D-D^*$.

(Think about each of them as a matrix containing all the pixel values of an image)

Now, our goal is to minimize the following objective function:

$L(D,D^*)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}d_i^2-\frac{1}{2n^2}(\sum_{i} d_i)^2+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}[(\nabla_xd_i)^2+(\nabla_yd_i)^2]$

where $\nabla_xd_i$ and $\nabla_yd_i$ are the horizontal and vertical [gradients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient) of the difference.

For further details [see the paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4734v4.pdf).

**What can be the derivative of** $L$ **w.r.t.** $D\; ?$  $(\frac{\partial L}{\partial D} = ?)$

Actually, I have a headache with the last term.

Many thanks in advance.

P.S.: if the 3rd term in unclear, let's check the answer for the first and the second terms.

Comment: When you define $d_i$ as $d_i=D-D^*$ you have an $i$ on the left hand side but not the right. This does not make sense given you later sum over $i$. Also it is not clear what $\nabla_x d_i$ and $\nabla_y d_i$ are (what does $D-D^*$ depend on that you have differentiated with respect to - surely these should be arguments of the function $L$)?

Comment: سلام همشری. معادله ی  $d_i=D-D^*$ چرا فقط یه اندیس آزاد داره؟ در ضمن مشتق افقی و عمودی یعنی چی؟  شاید این عباراتو رو کتاب شما تعریف کرده. بهتره تعریفشو بگی اینجا. :)

Comment: @smcc thanks, there are $n$ couples of $(D,D^*)$ so, $d_i$ is the difference of the $i-th$ couple.

Comment: Then please fix the notation. What about my other question in my comment above?

Comment: Actually, this is a copy of the objective equation in a paper. $L$ depends on both $D$ and $D^*$, but we wanna get the derivative of $L$ w.r.t just $D$.

Comment: Can you link to the paper?